# CRUD Operations on Grandchild using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my first question on this community, I hope someone can help.

I have 3 models: Parent, child and grandchild. Resource, Parameter and Metric. I create the controlers with entity framework and it generated all CRUD operations. My problem its basically the grandchild. When I go to create a new Metric (grandchild), I have the dropdownlist of all the Parameters (child), but I want first to choose the Resource, then that will list all the parameters from that resource so I can create the metric. I'm new on asp MVC and this might be a lil bit basic question but I couldn't find anything like this. Thanks

Here are my classes just in case.

```
public class Resource
{     
    public int ResourceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public int ParameterID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ResourceID { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }
}

public class Metric
{
    public int MetricID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParameterID { get; set; }
    public virtual Parameter Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do sounds like either a linked or cascading drop down list. I did a quick search and found this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/) that may help you.

You will need some JavaScript that listens to the selection changed event for the first list (parent), and then updates the second list (child) with the available values. Depending on your situation, you may then need to link the third list (grandchild) to load when the second list has its selection changed as well.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, but then I had a problem when trying to get the information from database, that link uses data generated on the same controller. But I kept looking on cascading drop down list and complemented with this tutorial that uses database. http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-cascading-dropdown-list.html